# How can I get keyboard/mouse plugged into a USB-C hub monitor to wake laptop from sleep?

Tags: usb, laptop, sleep, usb-c, usb-hub

I purchased an HP laptop using Windows 11, and a USB hub monitor (Asus), and connected the laptop, mouse, and keyboard into the monitor.

It's working fine, except the only thing that will wake it from sleep is the laptop keys and trackpad, and not the external keyboard and mouse.

I've tried the suggestion found on google, with the power management settings and selecting "allow this device to wake the computer", and not turning off power to usb devices when in sleep, but it's not working still.

Comment: when the monitor sleeps, does it perhaps power down the USB hub? Is there a setting in the monitor to control that?

Comment: Try a plain USB port on the laptop for the Mouse dongle. That should work.

Answer (score 2):

Yup, it indeed was a setting on the monitor itself, the hub was on "off when in standby" by default.